# How can I find a value from an array using another object value in MongoDB group aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate, aggregation

I have a collection where I want to find one data based on another object data:

```js
const data = [
{  _id :0, name:"jane",  joined : ISODate("2011-03-02"),  likes : 30, dislikes: 9},
{  _id :1, name: "joe",  joined : ISODate("2012-07-02"),  likes : 40, dislikes: 07},
{  _id : 2, name:"Ant",  joined : ISODate("2012-07-02"),  likes : 60, dislikes: 02}
]
```

From here I want to get the name who got most likes and I want to get the name who got maximum dislikes.

My code is like this:

```js
const parcel = await regionModel.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "likes": { $gt: 0 },
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      likes: {
        $max: "$likes"
      },
      dislikes: {
        $max: "$dislikes"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

In this code, I can get the maximum `likes` value and maximum `likes`, but how can I get the `name` or whole object based on the max `likes` and max `dislikes`?

**Required Output:**

```
likes: 60
MostLikedName: "Ant" ---OR--- {  _id : 2, name:"Ant",  joined : ISODate("2012-07-02"),  likes : 60, dislikes: 02}
dislikes. 09
mostDislikedName: "Jane" ---OR--- {  _id :0, name:"jane",  joined : ISODate("2011-03-02"),  likes : 30, dislikes: 9}
```

I tried to sort the the document but I can sort the document based on dislike or like. Also I was wondering if I can use `$cond` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sort and limit 1 to find the document with the maximum value. If you want to calculate the maximum for likes and dislikes in the same aggregation, one approach could be to use a $facet stage to get each document with the maximum.

```
  db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      maxLikes: [
        {$sort: {likes: -1}},
        {$limit: 1}
      ],
      maxDislikes: [
        {$sort: {dislikes: -1}},
        {$limit: 1}
      ]
    }
  },
  {$unwind: "$maxDislikes"},
  {$unwind: "$maxLikes"}
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zfNqmun-uHw)

Another alternative to get the maximum for likes and dislikes in a single aggregation is to use a `unionWith` stage, with this approach you get the two documents without transforming them:

```
  db.collection.aggregate([
    {$sort: {likes: -1}},
    {$limit: 1},
    {
      $unionWith: {
        coll: "collection",
        pipeline: [
          {$sort: {dislikes: -1}},
          {$limit: 1}
        ]
      }
    }
  ])
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/X41Jm_7yI3n)

Comment: Yes. That is the thing I am looking for. Thank you. But how can I extract the name and dislikes/likes value from here? Should I write another aggregation out of this or can you give me any clue?

Comment: The names and the number of likes and dislikes objects are in the result, you can add a project stage if you need them in a different format. I have added another alternative to get just the document with the max likes and the document without the max dislikes as they are stored in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for something like https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#examples

Comment: Thank you but I am not exactly looking for this. I want to get the max liked data object, max disliked data, and some more like max shared data object and from here I want to extract the name. $push is not exactly the way I want. I tried it already.